# I can't connect to internet via lan cable because 2032 battery died and my bios bios info is now empty

Tags: internet, serial, lan, bios

I have a compaq CQ61-112SL from about 5 years now... the main battery is almost dead, doesn't keep more then 10 minutes. anyway my problem is that my motherboard battery didn't have any more energy left a few days ago and since then I can't access internet through lan cable but only via wifi. I need cable though. I saw that on my BIOS setup page there were a bunch of parameters missing like serial number, UUID, product number and stuff like that. Also when I start the notebook it prints something like : No serial found. or something like that.

I don't really know if the reason why my lan cable doesn't work is the empty BIOS but i assume that's it.

If it's not please enlighten me. Or anyway tell me how to update the serial number and product number to the real ones (instead of the 0000000000000 that is now in my bios).

Comment: I downloaded HP DMI which should make it possible to set these variables on the BIOS but i'm on Windows 8 64bit and the executable file that I need to open for my laptop model says it can't run on 64 bit.

Comment: 1) Stack overflow isn't a forum, it's a place to ask questions so other people with a similar problem can get an answer. Reword your question

Comment: 2) Try serverfault, stackover flow is for programming not random hardware questions.